# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to generate SQL for predicate (...)

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I get the following problem:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to generate SQL for predicate (category == Basis) (problem on RHS)'

```
case "Basisfragen":
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category = Basis")
        break
```

Does anybody have  an idea why it doesn't work?
Wasn't able to find a helpful answer for Swift or to translate any Objective-C answer to a working one in Swift...

Thx!
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this that assume that category is a key or attribute with string type.

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category ==%@","Basis")
```

Comment: thx, that deletes the error but the result of the Fetch Request is empty. Do you have any idea how to solve this? I'm sure that the 'category' attribute exists and that some Items have a category attribute that is Basis?

Comment: no, another case returns an empty array and a third one shows only one object in the array but should show over 30 :(

Comment: Okay, I found out I got a nil. But your code line is working fine with the rest now. Thank you very much!